# JMeter - Access Log Sampler setting a default app. name

Tags: performance, jmeter

i'm trying to achieve the following:

i want to use a tomcat accesslog file and load it into jmeter and run it. The problem i run into is that for example a accesslog line looks like this:

"GET /MyApp/... HTTP/1.1"

What i need is to be able to change the applications name (MyApp). I did not find anything usefull if this is possible or how. I read however it could be done by using HTTP request default configuration. I could not get it working. I hope i could express my problem appropriate enough, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but why don't you just replace MyApp in your access.log?

Comment: yes this is what i do atm, however i don't like it doing it myself. It would be nice if jmeter could do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible out of the box but it should be by writing your own parser for the [Access Log Sampler](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access_Log_Sampler) or by extending it. The documentation explains which interfaces to implement and which classes to look at.